# Gekko model with variable delay

Tags: python, delay, gekko, mpc

I have a system with a non-constant delay. Does gekko support this type of problem and can it be handled in the MHE and MPC formulation?

Reading the docs I can see how to implement the delay, but I am not sure how the state estimation part of the MPC/MHE will handle this or if it is even capable to deal with such problems.

Comment: Variable delay makes sense for MHE, but in MPC the MV could just actuate at a different time. Could you give a potential use case for variable delay in MPC? Would it be a constant that is transferred from the MHE or do you have other ideas?

Comment: One example of variable delay is in a paper machine where the machine runs at different speeds. There is a stationary measuring point and thus as the speed of the machine changes so does the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to include variable time delay in estimation or control problems. There is a reformulation of the problem to allow for continuous 1st and 2nd derivatives that are needed for a gradient-based optimizer. I recommend that you use a cubic spline to create a continuous approximation of the discontinuous delay function. This way, the delay can be fractional such as `theta=2.3`. If the delay must be integer steps then set `integer=True` for the `theta` decision variable.

```py
theta_ub = 30 # upper bound to dead-time
theta = m.FV(0,lb=0,ub=theta_ub); theta.STATUS=1

# add extrapolation points
td = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-theta_ub,min(t)-1e-5,5),t))
ud = np.concatenate((u[0]*np.ones(5),u))
# create cubic spline with t versus u
uc = m.Var(u); tc = m.Var(t); m.Equation(tc==time-theta)
m.cspline(tc,uc,td,ud,bound_x=False)
```

Here is an example of one cycle of Moving Horizon Estimation with a first-order plus dead-time (FOPDT) model with variable time delay. This example is from the [Process Dynamics and Control online course](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/FirstOrderOptimization).

[image: FOPDT Variable Time Delay]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import CSV data file
# Column 1 = time (t)
# Column 2 = input (u)
# Column 3 = output (yp)
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/pdc/uploads/Main/data_fopdt.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
t = data['time'].values - data['time'].values[0]
u = data['u'].values
y = data['y'].values

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t; time = m.Var(0); m.Equation(time.dt()==1)

K = m.FV(2,lb=0,ub=10);      K.STATUS=1
tau = m.FV(3,lb=1,ub=200);  tau.STATUS=1
theta_ub = 30 # upper bound to dead-time
theta = m.FV(0,lb=0,ub=theta_ub); theta.STATUS=1

# add extrapolation points
td = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-theta_ub,min(t)-1e-5,5),t))
ud = np.concatenate((u[0]*np.ones(5),u))
# create cubic spline with t versus u
uc = m.Var(u); tc = m.Var(t); m.Equation(tc==time-theta)
m.cspline(tc,uc,td,ud,bound_x=False)

ym = m.Param(y); yp = m.Var(y)
m.Equation(tau*yp.dt()+(yp-y[0])==K*(uc-u[0]))

m.Minimize((yp-ym)**2)

m.options.IMODE=5
m.solve()

print('Kp: ', K.value[0])
print('taup: ',  tau.value[0])
print('thetap: ', theta.value[0])

# plot results
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,y,'k.-',lw=2,label='Process Data')
plt.plot(t,yp.value,'r--',lw=2,label='Optimized FOPDT')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,u,'b.-',lw=2,label='u')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Input')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```